# MS Access Crosstab query - sum of columns reported by month

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I am putting together a Crosstab and I want a report for multiple column values (all numbers) grouped by month. Here is the SQL I used. I understand that this won't bring back the desired results. every "timex" column has a different number in it. I want a query that will return the sum of the column grouped by month.

`TRANSFORM Sum(tblTimeTracking.time1+ tblTimeTracking.time2+ tblTimeTracking.time3+ tblTimeTracking.time4+ tblTimeTracking.time5+ tblTimeTracking.time6+ tblTimeTracking.time7+ tblTimeTracking.time8+ tblTimeTracking.time9+ tblTimeTracking.time10+ tblTimeTracking.time11+ tblTimeTracking.time12+ tblTimeTracking.time13+ tblTimeTracking.time14+ tblTimeTracking.time15+ tblTimeTracking.time16+ tblTimeTracking.time17+ tblTimeTracking.time18+ tblTimeTracking.time19+ tblTimeTracking.time20+ tblTimeTracking.time21+ tblTimeTracking.time22 ) AS Total
SELECT tbl_vlookup.Manager AS Manager
FROM tbl_vlookup INNER JOIN tblTimeTracking ON tbl_vlookup.[Associate Name] = tblTimeTracking.Associate
GROUP BY tbl_vlookup.Manager
PIVOT Format([Day],"yyyy-mm");`

```
Associate    Day          Time 1    Time 2  Time 3  Time 4  Time 5  Time 6  Time 7   
John Smith  12/1/9999       1         0       0      5.5      1      0.25   0.25
```

Comment: Are you saying you have a table with 22 time columns? If so why? You need to flatten it with a UNION query.

Comment: I do. They are all unique. It is a workforce tracker. Time 1 would be breaks, time 2 = filing, etc... I want to find what the total of all columns sorted by month

Comment: Please post sample data.

Comment: Added sample data.  There are multiple Associates and a lot of entries. @Remou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(q.Time1) AS SumOfTime1
SELECT q.Associate, q.Day
FROM (SELECT t.Associate, t.Day, t.Time1,"Time1" As TimeType
FROM tbl t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Associate, t.Day, t.Time2,"Time2" As TimeType
FROM tbl t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.Associate, t.Day, t.Time3,"Time3" As TimeType
FROM tbl t)  AS q
GROUP BY q.Associate, q.Day
PIVOT q.TimeType;
```

As I mentioned, you need to flatten the table. It only seems to be different types of data :)